# Problem with some database data after transferring asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, database-migration

I wrote a store site with asp.net web form that was on a shared host and had sql 2012. I bought a plesk managed virtual server with SQL 2016 due to increased traffic. After moving from the old hosting to the new hosting of my database, I had a problem.
The first product that I used to add cream using the control panel I wrote was seen in the panel and product list but was not seen using the sql query. I also took photos related to the product directly using the insert command in the management studio, where the relevant records were available.
The next day I saw the product record that was not previously seen in the database but was in my product list, but the photo record that was inserted directly was deleted. I called support to say that maybe the problem is with the previous sql host, that I changed the connection information to the previous host altogether, but they say that the database has no problem.
The main problem arose when a customer bought two bags and they were properly available in the panel. After a few hours, one of the bags was deleted from the database. This happened again after a few days, but there was no problem for the customers and their shopping cart and invoices, and these were the two cases. Since the site was working properly 8 years ago and this problem was not observed, I assumed that my code was correct.
I upgraded from sql 2012 to 2016 and use version 4.0 and the framework version of plesk program on the new server is 4.7.
Please advise me if there are any bugs in my code and check them, or is it from the database and migrating or backing up and restoring the database from 2012 to 2016 or from EF?

Comment: What is your connection string?  Sound like you have more than one version of the database.  If server is attached to a SQL Server than DO NOT use in the connection string "AttachDb".  It is already attached.  Make sure you use Server to specify the database.   Always test the database with SQL Server Management Studio using the same Server/Instance that is on the login window of SSMS.

Comment: I have completely changed the username and password of the previous database host,and in the web config I have two connection strings,one for SQL and one for Entity Framework.If I connect to two databases,all records must have a problem.Is there a problem in migrating from the 2012 version to the 2016 version of the database?Or I have to add a model of entity framework to my project from the beginning.I really do not know what to do.The problem sometimes arises twice.Even when I instinctively ordered the insert with the studio management,my data was deleted after one day.Does SQL have a cache?

Comment: No.  With Entity you first a to call the Context with a new statement which should do a query of the database and fill the Entity Classes.  You can check the SQL Server log files to see all the queries that were performed and any errors.  Changing the username and password does nothing except stop the code from running.  You need to change the connection string to make sure you are accessing the new database and not old.  You also have to make sure you are not using the localDb which is a mdf file that is not attached to the database. You probably are connecting to a localDb instead of server.

Comment: How can we begin answer this? It's configuration, it's two databases being involved. It's not even clear whether the 2012 database is still online, or which backup/restore process is running, or fallback scenarios, or any auditing tools, etc. etc. Also "Please advise me if there are any bugs in my code". What code?

Comment: The only way I can connect to the database is through web config, which points to a new server

Comment: I checked the codes and found a bug. There was no problem with the database. Thanks